# Empty Substring warning in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, substring, warnings

I have a for loop in php that is throwing a peculiar error.

```
for ($counter=1; $counter < count($cities); $counter++)
    $dataset[$cities[$counter]]=substr_count($votecontents, $cities[$counter]);
```

Error:

```
Warning: substr_count() [function.substr-count]: Empty substring in [OMITTED] on line 24
```

Line 24 is the second line I showed. I know that the array `$cities` is populated because I checked it right before. I start with `$counter` equaling one because I don't want to use the first entry of the array.

What's going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It simple means that `$cities[$counter]` is empty string. You need to add extra check before using substr_count function.

If you have for example code:

```
$array = array();

$array[] = '';
```

array will have one element, but when you use this element in substr_count function it will raise warning

Comment: Oh, nevermind... I figured it out myself. I'll give you some points anyway tho.